# How to Mean stack to list on port 8080

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, port, mean-stack

I am absolutely new to mean stack, but i am trying to get my root domain name to show the app directory running after i type grunt, but it only works at website.com:8080/!#/ how to git it to be website.com. I have tried modyfing the server. js below but to no success.

This is my server.js file

```
//Start the app by listening on <port>
var port = process.env.PORT || config.port;
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express app started on port ' + port);
```

Thanks.

Comment: By default browsers make requests against port 80 so if you switch the server to serve from port 80 you should be all good

Comment: By default it was set to the freaking variable, i dont appreciate the yelling adneo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the port `80` directly in your code **but** your application needs to run with `root` privileges if the port is less than `1024`.

IMO, a better way is to use `Apache` or `Nginx` (HTTP server on 80) with a reverse proxy to 8080. (https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+reverse+proxy)

Comment: what if i just chaged to port to 3000, which was the default i just chaged it to 8080 beacause i know very little about server stuff, and i was running tests based on my limited knowledge.than i wouldn't have the root permission error

Comment: also where in the app do i put my port number?